# Python, error TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Tags: python, visual-studio, bucles

soy nuevísimo en Python y suelo tener problemas muy simples jaja.

```
class Lista:

def buscarDato(self, lista, dato):

    for i in lista:
        if i == dato:
            print(dato)
```

El error es:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Se produce en la linea 5, donde se encuentra el for, ahí Python dice que "object"(? no es iterable ¿A qué se refiere?

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Cual es la llamada que haces a ese método?

Comment: En todo caso, el error se explica solo. Lo que estas usando en el for (o sea, `lista`) no es algo iterable.... por eso hay que mirar que es lo que estás utilizando como el primer parámetro de la llamada a buscarDato

Comment: Donde esta la lista que va a iterar?

Comment: Solucionado, únicamente me había olvidado de darle valores a la lista de parámetro, por eso no era iterable, jaja!